# How to tell if I use ObjectContext API or DbContext API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

I've got two projects with different database models (though the same Entity Framework Version 5.0.0).

Their queries look like the following:

Project 1:

```
if (_db.Entry(customer).State == EntityState.Detached)
```

Project 2:

```
if (customer.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
```

These are the differences, as well as other minor things.

How can I tell which version of the Entity Framework (when the DLL version matches) each project is using? Does it make sense to update the "older" version to the "newer" model version? What are the benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project 1 uses the `DbContext` API because only this context type has an `Entry` method.

Project 2 most likely uses `ObjectContext` with entities derived from `EntityObject` and `Customer` inherits the `EntityState` from there. If `Customer` has a custom `EntityState` property, it's not possible to distinguish with your single line. Hit F12 twice - once on the `customer` variable which directs you to the declaration and then on the type (probably `Customer`) of that variable to see the class declaration and to check if it derives from `EntityObject`.

The fact that the EF5 assembly in Project 2 is referenced means nothing. It might be unused in the code or the code only uses a few helper methods (like the lambda version of `Include`), but it doesn't seem to use all the core features of `DbContext`. It will reference the EF classes in the .NET framework assemblies (`System.Data.Entity.dll`, etc.).

Upgrading project 2 is worth to consider because all newer development of EF follows the POCO approach (instead of the `EntityObject` approach).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do I need to delete the old database model and re-create it using the same (old model, but new DLL) project 2? Or is there some "upgrade mechanism"? By the way: `customer` derives from `EntityObject`. That means, it's using the "old" way, doesn't it?

Comment: @SeToY: Yes, it's the old way. Can you ask a separate question about upgrading? I am unsure what the smoothest approach is and don't want to drive you into trouble. You also have to expect some code changes (for example the line in your question won't work anymore and maybe more). Put as much info as possible into your question (compiler version, .NET version, EF version, DB version, if you start with an existing DB schema or with model first, etc.)